# Yii and Dropdown in a form

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

I am new to Yii framework.

I have a form with three fields. I need one of those be a select drop down element that its data comes from previously added data which are in mysql table.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a model set up for the table that contains the data you want to use in your dropdown list you can use the [`CHtml::dropDownList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail) method the render a dropdown list, and [`CHtml::listData()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) to render that model into items for the list, for example;

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList(
    'attribute_name',
    '',
    CHtml::listData(MyOtherModel::model()->findAll(),'id','name')
);
```

I use Gii a lot, which uses CActiveForm widget to display forms, if your form uses CActiveForm too you could render your dropdown something like;

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method'=>'get',
));

...

echo $form->label($model,'attribute_name');
echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'attribute_name',
    CHtml::listData(MyOtherModel::model()->findAll(),'id','name')
);

...

$this->endWidget();
```

Note that CActiveForm uses [`CHtml::activeDropDownList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail%28%29) rather than `CHtml::dropDownList()` that I used in my first example, hence the slight difference in syntax between my two examples.

Comment: Thank you. I used the second approche. ‌But how can I added a blank option before items in listData?

Comment: you could `array_merge(array(''=>''),CHtml::listData(MyOtherModel::model()->findAll(),'id','name'))` to prepend a blank array item at the start of the list.

Comment: thank you again. would you answer another question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993785/return-a-row-of-a-table-using-active-record-in-yii