# return a row of a table using Active Record in Yii

Tags: activerecord, yii

I want to return a field of a row of table which has id = 4 in a model for example Post.

Which one should I use find() method or findByAttributes() ? And what is the correct syntax for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab a model by its primary key I'd suggest `[findByPk()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByPk-detail). It's one of the most simple methods to use;

```
$id = 4;
$model = Post::model()->findByPk($id);
```

For other method syntaxes, have a read through the [Yii Active Record wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#reading-record) and [Yii Active Record documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord), they're really helpful when starting out.